# Hilos y websockets

Tags: c#, websocket

Quiero hacer un tictactoe con webscokets, cuando ingresa el primer cliente le devuelve su ranking, pero cuando ingresa el segundo en lugar de iniciar la partida lo que hace es como si se eliminara el primer cliente y continua esperando por el segundo

Codigo del hilo:

```
class HiloJugador
{
    private TcpClient socket;
    private LinkedList<TcpClient> usuariosSocket;
    private StreamWriter writer;
    private StreamReader reader;
    private Usuario usuario;
    private Partida partida;
    private Thread hilo;
    private Utils utils;
    private char[] cbuf;
    private String recibido;

    public HiloJugador(TcpClient socket, LinkedList<TcpClient> usuariosSocket, StreamWriter writer, StreamReader reader, Partida partida, List<Usuario> listaUsuario)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.usuariosSocket = usuariosSocket;
        this.writer = writer;
        this.reader = reader;
        this.partida = partida;
        this.utils = new Utils(listaUsuario);
        this.cbuf = new char[512];
        //Buscar al usuario
        this.buscarUsuario(listaUsuario);
        writer.Write("\n\n--------------RANKING-----------------"
            + "\n" + utils.imprimirRanking() + "\n\n"
            + "TU PUNTAJE ES DE: " + this.usuario.Puntaje);
        writer.Flush();
        this.validarPartida();
    }

    private void validarPartida()
    {
        if (this.partida.Usuario1 == null)
        {
            this.partida.Usuario1 = usuario;
            this.partida.SiguienteJugador = usuario;
            usuario.Marca = 'X';
        }
        else if (this.partida.Usuario2 == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Crea el segundo usuario");
            this.partida.Usuario2 = usuario;
            if (this.partida.Usuario1.Marca == 'X')
            {
                usuario.Marca = 'O';
            }
            else
            {
                usuario.Marca = 'X';
            }
        }
        this.hilo = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        this.hilo.Start();

    }



    private void buscarUsuario(List<Usuario> listaUsuario)
    {
        String nombreUsuario = null;
        Boolean agregarNuevoUsuario = true;
        while (true)
        {
            nombreUsuario = this.recibirSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            agregarNuevoUsuario = true;
            foreach (Usuario usuario in listaUsuario)
            {
                if (usuario.Nombre.Equals(nombreUsuario))
                {
                    if (usuario.Jugando)
                    {
                        /*
                            Ya esta jugando en otro cliente con este mismo nombre
                        */
                        writer.Write("false");
                        writer.Flush();
                        agregarNuevoUsuario = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    this.usuario = usuario;
                    usuario.Jugando = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (agregarNuevoUsuario)
            {
                this.usuario = new Usuario(nombreUsuario);
                this.usuario.Marca = 'X';
                listaUsuario.Add(usuario);
                usuario.Jugando = true;
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    private void mostrarTablero()
    {
        try
        {
        writer.Write(this.partida.mostrarTablero());
            writer.Flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Se perdio la conexion con un usuario");
            this.matarHilo();
        }
    }

    private void mostrarTablero(String mensaje)
    {
        try
        {
        writer.Write(mensaje + "\n" + this.partida.mostrarTablero());
        writer.Flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Se perdio la conexion con un usuario");
            this.matarHilo();
        }
    }

    private String mostrarEstadoPartida(Boolean movimientoValido)
    {
        String estadoPartida = this.partida.tableroTransformado() + "\n";
        estadoPartida += (movimientoValido) + "\n";
        estadoPartida += (this.partida.SiguienteJugador == this.usuario) + "\n";
        if (this.partida.JugadorGanador!= null &&
                this.partida.JugadorGanador == this.usuario)
        {
            estadoPartida += "1";
            this.partida.reiniciarPartida();
        }
        else if (this.partida.JugadorGanador != null &&
              this.partida.JugadorGanador != this.usuario)
        {
            estadoPartida += "-1";
            this.partida.reiniciarPartida();
        }
        else if (this.partida.tableroLleno())
        {
            estadoPartida += "0";
            this.partida.reiniciarPartida();
        }
        else
        {
            estadoPartida += "";
        }
        return estadoPartida;
    }

    private String mostrarEstadoPartida()
    {
        String estadoPartida = this.partida.tableroTransformado() + "\n";
        if (this.usuario.GanoPartida != null)
        {
            estadoPartida += this.usuario.GanoPartida;
            this.usuario.GanoPartida =null;
            this.partida.JugadorGanador =null;
        }
        return estadoPartida;
    }

    private String recibirSocket()
    {
        cbuf = new char[512];
        recibido = "";
        reader.Read(cbuf);
        foreach (char c in cbuf)
        {
            recibido += c;
            if (c == 00)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return recibido;
    }

    private Boolean esperarMovimiento() 
    {
    writer.Write("Es tu TURNO");
    writer.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine("5");
    return partida.agregarMovimiento(Int32.Parse(recibirSocket()), this.usuario.Marca);
    }

    private void matarHilo()
    {
        usuario.Jugando = false;
        this.partida.removerUsuario(usuario);
        this.partida.reiniciarPartida();
        this.usuariosSocket.Remove(this.socket);
        this.hilo.Abort();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (this.partida.Usuario2 == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Esperando a otro jugador...");
            }
            else if (this.partida.SiguienteJugador == this.usuario)
            {
                //                this.mostrarTablero();
                try
                {
                    /*
                        Muestra el estado de la partida cuando le seda el turno
                    */
                    writer.Write(this.mostrarEstadoPartida());
                    writer.Flush();
                    Console.WriteLine("2");
                    /*
                        Muestra el estado de la partida cuando termina el turno
                    */
                    String respuesta = this.mostrarEstadoPartida(this.esperarMovimiento());
                    writer.Write(respuesta);
                    writer.Flush();
                    Console.WriteLine("23");
                    //                    this.mostrarTablero("Esperando el movimiento de tu compañero");
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Se perdio la conexion con un usuario");
                    this.matarHilo();
                }
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error en el Sleep");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Mi Main:

class Program
    {

```
    private readonly int puerto = 8088;
    //private List<TcpClient> usuarios;
    private LinkedList<TcpClient> usuarios;
    private List<Usuario> listaUsuario;
    private StreamWriter writer;
    private StreamReader reader;

    public Program()
    {
        usuarios = new LinkedList<TcpClient>();
        //usuarios = new List<TcpClient>();
        listaUsuario = new List<Usuario>();
    }



    public void escuchar()
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.54"), puerto);
        server.Start();

        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Esperando jugadores");
            Partida partida = new Partida();
            while (true)
            {
                //Espera a un jugador
                TcpClient usuario = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                if (partida.Usuario2 != null)
                {
                    partida = new Partida();
                }
                reader = new StreamReader(usuario.GetStream());
                writer = new StreamWriter(usuario.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine("Se conecto un jugador");
                //Se agrega el socket a la lista
                //usuarios.Add(usuario);
                usuarios.AddLast(usuario);
                writer.Write("Ya te agregue\n por favor ingrese su usuario".ToCharArray());
                writer.Flush();
                new HiloJugador(usuario, usuarios, writer, reader, partida, listaUsuario);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }





    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Program programa = new Program();
        programa.escuchar();



    }
}
```

output del server:

Se conecta el cliente y espera por otro, pero cuando se conecta el otro cliente muestra un 1 que significa que hay un solo cliente:

Esperando jugadores

Se conecto un jugador

1

Esperando a otro jugador...

Esperando a otro jugador...

Se conecto un jugador

Esperando a otro jugador...

1

Esperando a otro jugador...

Comment: Con que estas haciendo el servicio? y con que queres mantener los datos? porque lo norma de un servicio web es que cada cliente que lo consulta es una nueva instancia del cliente.  No tiene conocimiento de que haya una sesion abierta, a no ser que trabajes con WCF

Comment: @RamiroBarone Lo estoy trabajando todo de manera local por el momento y los datos en memoria